# Javascript: Refere to Div Tags

Tags: javascript, image, animation, html, tags

I have a CSS style sheet that has the following:

```
div.box img {

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  display:inline;
}
```

This div tag basically re-sizes my image. My HTML file has the following:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function doMove(){

//move object
 }


 </script>

 </head>

 <body>
<h1>JavaScript Animation</h1>

<div class="box">
<img src="dp.png"/>
</div>
```

I want to be able to move this box to the left once doMove() is called. How do i refer to my DIV tag in my stylesheet in javascript?

Comment: Give an 'id' to your box, and get a reference to it in Javascript using document.getElementById()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want only the `div` with the class-name of `box`:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divsNum = divs.length;
for (i=0; i<divsNum; i++){
    if (divs[i].className == 'box'){
        divs[i].style.marginLeft = '-100px';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n74yq/).

Comment: You might want to see if *getElementsByClassName* is supported first, or even *querySelectorAll* to make the search a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to move that one div, the easiest thing would be to assign an id to that div:

```
<div id="box1" class="box>
```

And then to reference that div in your javascript, you would do:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="yourDiv" class="box">
<img src="dp.png"/>
</div>

 function doMove(){
  var yourDiv = document.getElementById("yourDiv");
 }
```